# Rust generic memoization - doesn't satisfy Clone

Tags: generics, rust, memoization

I am sitting over an exercise to build generic memoization in safe Rust. Memoization as a concept is straight forward. You create a value containing a function, on the first call you execute the function and store the value, and on all subsequent calls you return the stored value. This comes handy, for example, to cache and reuse results from requests.

I made a few considerations:

1. Interior mutability shields the API
2. Results should pretty print
3. Multiple owners should be okay.

With that in mind, I chose Cell type for interior mutability and an optional wrapped Rc to count references when the value is set. A generic type T needs to implement copy for the Cell type and Debug for the pretty print. The resulting struct looks like this:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct Memo<T:, F: Fn() -> T> where T: Debug + Copy {
    cell: Cell<Option<Rc<T>>>,
    func: F,
}
```

The type implementation really only needs two methods: new & get, as show below.

```rust
impl<T, F: Fn() -> T> Memo<T, F> where T: Debug + Copy {
    pub fn new(func: F) -> Memo<T, F> {
        Memo {
            cell: Cell::new(None),
            func,
        }
    }

    pub fn get(&self) -> Rc<T> {
        return match self.cell.get() {
            Some(rc) => {
                rc // return the cached value
            }
            None => {
                let value = (self.func)(); 
                self.cell.set(Some(Rc::new(value))); 
                let rc = self.cell.get().unwrap();
                rc // return the cached value
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The idea of the new method really is to set the cell to None by default, and upon the first call of the get method pattern match, call the function, and replace None with Some result returned by the function.

However, the get method throws a compile error pointing out that Option does not satisfy copy trait.

```
error[E0599]: the method `get` exists for struct `Cell<Option<Rc<T>>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:19:32
    |
19  |         return match self.cell.get() {
    |                                ^^^
    |
    |
518 | pub enum Option<T> {
    | ------------------ doesn't satisfy `Option<Rc<T>>: Copy`
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `Option<Rc<T>>: Copy`
```

The cause of the error is not so clear to me because I though the type bound would ensure that T must implement the copy trait required by cell.get(), which returns a copy of its value. Apparently that is not the case.

The first question I have is how do I fix the get implementation?

From there, it would be great to understand the issue at hand because, the Option type in Rust actually has a derived Copy implementation so somehow I am missing something important.

When I add the derive annotation for the struct, the error message becomes a bit more apparent.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Copy)]
pub struct Memo<T:, F: Fn() -> T> where T: Debug + Copy {
    cell: Cell<Option<Rc<T>>>,
    func: F,
}
```

```bash
5 | #[derive(Debug, Copy)]
  |                 ^^^^
6 | pub struct Memo<T:, F: Fn() -> T> where T: Debug + Copy {
7 |     cell: Cell<Option<Rc<T>>>,
  |     ------------------------- this field does not implement`Copy`
```

I understand the issue, somehow the cell doesn't implement copy, but it's not so clear to me why. My best guess is that Rc triggers the error, but how do I fix it?

Finally, if I were to replace Rc with Arc, would this implementation become thread-safe?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Solution: Remove Rc.

Comment: `Rc<T>` can't be `Copy`, even if `T: Copy`, so `Option<Rc<T>>` also can't ever be `Copy`. That is why `.get()` on that `Cell<Option<...>>` is not implemented. The reason `Rc<T>` can't be `Copy` regardless of `T: Copy` is that copying the `Rc` requires incrementing the reference counter, which a simple bitwise copy can't do.

Comment: Thank you, removing Rc and the derive copy actually fixes the code.